# How can I derive Mel-frequency cepstral coefficients from an audio recording on my Pi?

Tags: audio

I have recorded my voice with mini mic USB with command line on terminal  `arecord /home/pi/Desktop/test.wav -D sysdefault:CARD=1`, with 8000 rate mono channel. I want to looked for the [Mel coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum) for my audio with
jameslyons/python_speech_features, but there is an error

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/io/wavfile.py", line 166, in read
    data = _read_data_chunk(fid, comp, noc, bits, mmap=mmap)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/io/wavfile.py", line 71, in _read_data_chunk
    data = numpy.fromstring(fid.read(size), dtype=dtype)
ValueError: read length must be positive or -1
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm assuming you've written some code that uses the python_speech_features - it would be helpful if you included it in your post.